# What is wrong with this "find all vim swap files and remove them with a confirmation" command?

Tags: find, rm

I am trying to remove all vim swap file `*.swp` and remove them with a confirmation. The `find` command found the files, but `rm` says `No such file or directory` with the `-i` option. When I hardcode the path of the file and just use `rm -i` then it seems to work.

See below

```
(doors)hobbes3@hobbes3 ~/Sites $ find mysite mysite_BAK -name *.swp -exec 'rm -i {}' \;
find: rm -i mysite/templates/.base.html.swp: No such file or directory
find: rm -i mysite/templates/doors/orders/.create.html.swp: No such file or directory
find: rm -i mysite/templates/doors/orders/.detail.html.swp: No such file or directory
find: rm -i mysite/templates/doors/orders/.list.html.swp: No such file or directory
(doors)hobbes3@hobbes3 ~/Sites $ rm -i mysite/templates/.base.html.swp 
remove mysite/templates/.base.html.swp? n
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong with the `-exec` option. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually I just tried without the `-i` option and it still gave the same errors. Hmmm...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is generated by *find*, not *rm*.

The reason is that you have written it so `'rm -i <file>'` is the single argument. This shall be rewritten:

```
find mysite mysite_BAK -name '*.swp' -exec rm -i '{}' \;
```

so find gets multiple arguments after "-exec" and treats the first one as command and others as the command arguments.

Comment: You can also leave out the quotes around `{}`

Comment: Good practice to use `"*.swp" ` instead of just `*.swp`; The latter doesn't work in zsh, because of how the shells treat wildcards differently.

Comment: @metasoarous thanks, it's also useful. I corrected initially only spec for '{}' but not rest of line. Zsh isn't the only for this; my bash will also fail due to "failglob" option in my default config.

Answer (score 8):

UPDATED ANSWER:

if you are using bash version >4.0 you could use the globstar feature, it is very easy:

```
shopt -s globstar
rm -i **/*.swp
```

This also works with filenames that contain spaces!

The `shopt -s globstar` part will activate the recursive `**` matching in bash. You can put this in your `.bashrc` and be happy forever and ever.

OLD ANSWER:

I usually find it easier to use simple tools combined

cd to dir and then:

```
rm -i `find . | grep .swp$`
```

its easier to remember (if performance is not an issue)!

Warning: Only use this if your filenames don't contain spaces.

Comment: Wow, this is really easy and helpful at the same time! Thanks! I will use this from now on instead of complex find

Comment: This will fail if any subdir name or filename found contains spaces.

Comment: @Dubu True, i will edit to reflect that

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I would run,

```
find mysite mysite_BAK -type f -name .\*.sw? -exec rm -i {} ";"
```

VIM's swap file does not only end in .swp. If .swp exists, VIM would create .swo, then .swn, and so on. Also, swap files are prefixed with a dot (.), e.g., .file1.rb.swp

Other ways to find and delete VIM's swap files, without the confirmation (-i):

```
find some_dir -type f -name .\*.sw? | xargs rm 
find some_dir -type f -name .\*.sw? -exec rm {} ";"
find some_dir -type f -name .\*.sw? -delete  # -delete option does not work in Git Bash
```

Without "-type f", you would get an error when deleting a directory. Also, the `\` in `.\*.sw?` makes it compatible in multiple platforms.